# Flutter flavors deprecation

Tags: flutter, android-productflavors, dart-define

I am working on a project for a client and deciding on whether to use flavors or dart-define for environment config.

I like that flavors is built into the framework and there's a lot of documentation on how to get it working.

Is there a move away from flavors to dart-define for config and is the flutter team planning on deprecating flavors in favour of dart-define ?

Comment: You should reach out to flutter documentations / forum. This is not the place for those type of general questions

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.